# My code isn't working and I don't know why. C programming

Tags: c, loops, pointers, switch-statement, malloc

I tried to fix it but it keeps going into a loop saying "Invalid Input" and the end even though I put a break; I cannot figure out what it is, can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int *ptr1, *ptr2;
int num, num2, product, sum, quotient;

ptr1 = &num;
ptr2 = &num2;

char *c;
char choice;

//p = malloc (sizeof(num));
//c = malloc (sizeof(choice));


//-----------------------------------------------------------
//Inputs/Intro Statements
//------------------------------------------------------------
ptr1 = malloc (sizeof(*c));
ptr2 = malloc (sizeof(choice));

   printf("Enter your two integers:\n");
       scanf("%d", &num);
   
   printf("Enter another integer: \n");
       scanf("%d", &num2);
   
   printf("Now, enter a or A to show the sum, p or P to show the product or d or D to show the division of the first by the second:\n");
       scanf("%c", &choice);
   
c = &choice;

//------------------------------------------------------------

do {
switch(choice) {
    case 'A': //addition function
        sum = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
        printf("The sum of the tewo intergrs are: &sum /n");
        break;
    
    case 'P': //product
        product = *ptr1 * *ptr2;
        printf("The product of &num & &num2 are: &product /n");
        break;
    
    case 'D': //division
        quotient = *ptr1 / *ptr2;
        printf("The quotient of &num & &num2 are: &quotient \n");
        break;
        
    case 'Q': //quit
        printf("Goodbye");
        break;
        
    default: //just in case something goes wrong
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        break;
    }
}while (choice!= 'Q');
```

Comment: Spelling, grammar, coding errors - you've got a lot to fix here...

Comment: did you use your debugger to look at choice after the scanf call

Comment: notice that you done give the user a chance to correct their mistake.

Comment: where do you change choice in the loop?

Comment: move the scanf into the do loop, at least then you will make some progress. Main point though - use your debugger